# How to configure Api-platform to return simple JSON instead of JSON-LD?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to use refine.dev with Api-platform, but all the responses are in JSON-LD, and I need them as simple JSON.

How can I configure that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to send requests specifying Header `Accept: application/json`

```
GET /api/action
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48
```

If you want json to be the default in Swager UI, then you can specify the type globally in the `config/packages/api_platform.yaml` file

```
api_platform:
    formats:
        json: ['application/json']
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are declaring your collectionOperations or itemOperiation in your entity you can set the needed formats.

```json
collectionOperations: [
        'get ' => [
            'formats' => ['json'],
        ],
```

You can look at this documentation
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/content-negotiation/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
@ApiResource(formats= {"json"})
```

It works for me.